# Convert array to string using an object from a different class

Tags: java

Hello I'm very new to Java and currently I'm trying to convert an array, that is a playfield, into a string through using a method(object) I created in a different class . This is what I have tried:

```
public class Testing
{
public static void main(String[] args) {

//create an empty playfield that is 10x10
Board emptyBoard = new Board(10,10);

//convert playfield to string and save it in new variable
String newBoard = convertToString(emptyBoard); // this throws an error saying "cannot resolve method 'convertToString(...)'


//now show the playfield as a string
System.out.println(newBoard);
}
}
```

The method convertToString lies in another class called ArrayToString, if that matters for any reason and "convertToString" should take in a Board and return a String. Any ideas on how to solve this kind of problem? :)

Comment: The answer is here: [How to call a method in another class in Java?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4593232/how-to-call-a-method-in-another-class-in-java).

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How to call a method in another class in Java?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4593232/how-to-call-a-method-in-another-class-in-java)

Comment: Do you mean I should try:      emptyBoard.convertToString(newBoard)?
Because that doesn't seem to work. @P.Soutzikevich

Comment: You should do `ArrayToString. convertToString(emptyBoard);`if `convertToString` is a static method, otherwise you need to do `new` on the class just like with `Board`

Comment: I can't see the `Board` class code, nor the `convertToString()` method, so I can't tell you what will work. If the convertToString method is implemented in the Board class, then yes. My suggestion is to download [this book](https://github.com/Shailendra-Java/Library/blob/master/Java%20-%20The%20Complete%20Reference%2C%209th%20Edition%20-%20Herbert%20Schildt.pdf) and study from it

Answer (score 0):

```
package foo;

// add static import to not write it before method name
import static foo.ArrayToString;

public class Testing {
    public static void main(String[] args) {
        // method should be static, because you don't use new ArrayToString().convertToString(emptyBoard)
        String newBoard = convertToString(emptyBoard);
    }
}
```

---

```
package foo;

public class ArrayToString {
    // should be static method
    public static String convertToString(Board board) {}
}
```