# Calling a method from a one class to another

Tags: java, android, sqlite

I wrote this method in one class for checking if a table exists in my database or not:

```
public boolean DoesTableExist(String tableName) {
    SQLiteDatabase mDatabase = openOrCreateDatabase("privdb",MODE_PRIVATE,null);

    Cursor cursor = mDatabase.rawQuery("select DISTINCT tbl_name from sqlite_master where tbl_name = '"+tableName+"'", null);
    if(cursor!=null) {
        if(cursor.getCount()>0) {
            cursor.close();
            return true;

        }
        cursor.close();
    }

    return false;
}
```

I now would like to call this method in other activites or classes, without writing the same code everytime in every file.
How can I do that?

Answer (score 2):

Normally you'd invoke methods in another class by instantiating the class and then calling the method.  For instance, if the class that the method was in was named `DatabaseUtils`, you'd do the following:

```
DatabaseUtils dbUtils = new DatabaseUtils();
boolean exists = dbUtils.doesTableExist("tablename"); 
                      // ^ note that the normal Java convention is to make
                      //   method names start with a lower case letter
```

However, this has the feel of a "utility" method (the object presumably doesn't store any state, and thus there's no real need to instantiate it), and a common way of handling those are to make the method static, like so:

```
public static boolean doesTableExist(String tableName) {
```

That causes the method to exist on the class definition itself, instead of on a specific instance of a class, and allows you to do the following:

```
boolean exists = DatabaseUtils.doesTableExist("tablename");
```

Comment: That's one hell of a good answer, thank you. One more question: Calling this method from another class it gives me a NullPointer: java.lang.NullPointerException: Attempt to invoke virtual method 'android.database.sqlite.SQLiteDatabase android.content.Context.openOrCreateDatabase(java.lang.String, int, android.database.sqlite.SQLiteDatabase$CursorFactory)' on a null object reference - if the table doesn't exist, while calling it directly in my class it gives me a "false" as boolean. This sounds so wrong, I don't know how I even write it to you but I can't figure out why this is happening

Answer (score 0):

Make a instance of the class that method is in, create a get method and call method through that instance. 
Other option is to define method as a static and call it that way.

Instance:

```
ClassName classInstance = new ClassName();
classInstance.getMethod(parametar);
```

Static:

```
ClassName.methodName(parametar);
```

Here is more about that:
[How to call a method in another class in Java?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4593232/how-to-call-a-method-in-another-class-in-java)

Answer (score 0):

That would be a nice one to put in a "utils" package. 
Create a new Java package named "utils", add a new class, such as "DatabaseUtils.java" and make it look something like this:

```
    public class DatabaseUtils {

    public boolean DoesTableExist(String tableName) {
                SQLiteDatabase mDatabase = openOrCreateDatabase("privdb",MODE_PRIVATE,null);

                Cursor cursor = mDatabase.rawQuery("select DISTINCT tbl_name from sqlite_master                 where tbl_name = '"+tableName+"'", null);
                if(cursor!=null) {
                    if(cursor.getCount()>0) {
                        cursor.close();
                        return true;
                    }
                    cursor.close();
                }
                return false;
            }

    }
```

Now you can reference it from other places like this:

```
    public class main {

            public static void main(String [] args)
                    boolean isTableExisting = DatabaseUtils.doesTableExist("yourTableName")
                    System.out.println("Table existing? " + isTableExisting);
            }
    }
```

Probably you'll need to pass the name of the database as well ("privdb") or reference to where the method "openOrCreateDatabase(...)"  is located.

When your database does exist, it will print `"Table existing? true"`

Comment: Why is the MODE_PRIVATE not possible in this method / class, instead I have to put "null" on the ErrorHandler and the FactoryCursor like this: 
SQLiteDatabase mDatabase = SQLiteDatabase.openOrCreateDatabase("privdb",null,null); ?